# javaee project directory structure need understanding

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to java but got experience in .NET. I was developing CRUD in Servlet/JSP/JDBC for learning. During development wanted to properly name the packages and files which will be using.

I feel uncomfortable if I don't properly name which fits for javaEE projects.

I searched alot on this and finally decided to use this type of naming. Please see below directory and suggest me if I can fix it more from your development experience.

[image: javaEE Directory structure]

***Should I*** use one Controller for all the CRUD and related User operation in one single controller called UserController because if I have admin,product etc pages that will make lots of controller each for per page?

```
User --> Properties only (POJO)
UserDAO --> Interface
UserDAOImpl --> Methods for CRUD etc
```

I will switch to MVC frameworks soon and will explore JSF, Spring and Struts.

Answer (score 1):

1. The accepted naming convention is to use reversed domain name you own for your projects so that classes are unique across whole world. I don't own any domain but I typically use `com.blogspot.nurkiewicz`
2. It is not really agreed in the community whether you should keep classes in packages based on use-cases or layer. You have packages for DAOs, for DTOs and controllers. I prefer having package for user-related use cases, holding all classes in one place.
3. If you can, use one controller for all user-related actions. However once it gets too big, split it into groups of related functionalities (e.g. `UserCrudController`, `UserPermissionsController`...)
4. I am missing the service layer here - something that mediates between view layer (controllers) and raw data access.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you give me example for 1 and 2 from my above screen shot please that would be very helpful.